# Windows Form Custom Action (dll)

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I have a Windows Form Application and have created a Windows Installer using the Wizard from Visual Studio 2010.
Once the application installs, I would like to run an action from another Assembly I have written. The code I am trying to run is in an Assembly called RegistrationController and is referenced by the Windows Form application, such that I would like to run:

```
var controller = new RegistrationController();
controller.Register("Adrian");
```

once the application has successfully installed.
I can't seem to find how to add the action.

Thanks in advance, 
Adrian

Comment: I think this MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9cdb5eda(v=vs.100)) will help.